# java.util.GregorianCalendar

Tags: java

Привет. я с java  только знакомлюсь. Вот возникла проблема с выводом текущего года, дня в отдельности. Данный код возвращает "1" вместо "2011". В чем моя ошибка?

```
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();  
int year = now.get(calendar.YEAR);  
System.out.println(year);
```

Comment: А что такое calendar ? Если предположить что Calendar, а не calendar, то всё должно работать.

Comment: да все верно Calendar. но нет не работает. да к стати, ошибка на переменной YEAR. ее приходится объявлять как переменную

Comment: Кого объявлять как переменную?? Каким образом вы её объявляете? :OO Что-то вы там не то делаете..

Answer (score 3):

Держу пари, что вы делаете не так, как написали в вопросе. Настораживает, что код YEAR равен одному.. видимо, вы печатете не результат get, а само значение YEAR.

```
[cy6ergn0m@localhost 6]$ cat Main.java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));

                GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
                System.out.println(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));

                System.out.println(Calendar.YEAR);
        }
}

[cy6ergn0m@localhost 6]$ javac Main.java
[cy6ergn0m@localhost 6]$ java Main
2011
2011
1
[cy6ergn0m@localhost 6]$
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Мой косяк, обозвал свой класс "Calendar" от этого и не работало.

Answer (score 1):

```
  int year = new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR);
  GregorianCalendar d = new GregorianCalendar(year, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Это решение в случае необходимости вставки года в новый объект GregorianCalendar =)